# Adding other objects (scalarbar, axes, etc) in Mayavi figure for offline prevents visualization of data

Tags: python, data-visualization, mayavi

I am displaying some volumetric scalar data and quickly rendering the scene and saving the results to a png. This all works fine. However if I add some helpful objects such as a scalarbar or even axes to the figure it only renders the newly added scalarbar or axes.

An example,

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

x, y, z = np.ogrid[-10:10:20j, -10:10:20j, -10:10:20j]
s = np.sin(x*y*z)/(x*y*z)

mlab.options.offscreen = True
fig = mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(1., 1., 1.), size=(500, 500))
fig.scene.anti_aliasing_frames = 0

mlab.pipeline.volume(mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(s))
mlab.scalarbar() # commenting this out correctly renders, but no scalarbar

mlab.savefig('test.png')
```

This is actually used to create an animation, so I need to render offscreen. How can I display the volumetric data and the scalarbar?

Comment: What version of mayavi are you using?

Comment: 4.3.1, It was installed through the Anaconda Python distribution under Fedora-20 64-bit Linux

Comment: Hmm.. I am unable to reproduce the problem by running your code snippet; the axes and colorbar show up correctly in the output figure (I added `mlab.axes(color=(0,0,0))`). There were some improvements and bugfixes to offscreen rendering in 4.3.1, so I figured that might be the cause.

Comment: How are you running it? I was just calling 'python script.py'

Comment: Okay, using mayavi isn't much different. I'll wait until 4.3.2 hits pypi

Comment: That is how I was running it as well. The fixes should be present in 4.3.1. The only thing I can think of is that it may be possible that it is some obscure graphics driver error.